# Find an isomorphic map from the space of polynomials into 2-tuple polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

We are told that $F[x] \oplus F[x]$ is the space of 2-tuples of polynomials ($F[x]$ is the set of all polynomials). We must find an isomorphic map $S : F[x] \to F[x] \oplus F[x]$.

I am not sure if I am correct, but would this work: let $y \in F[x]$ then define $S(y) = (y, y^{-1})$. Would this satisfy the conditions given? Also, how would I show that any correct map satisfies such conditions?

**EDIT:** Actually, this will not work as not all polynomials will have an inverse I think. In this case, I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks! Helen

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It might be easier to go the other way and send $\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle$ to $p(x^2)+xq(x^2)$.

Note that your approach wouldn't give you a surjection even if $y^{-1}$ always existed, because each coordinate completely determines the other.

Comment: How would I go the other way round when I need a map from $F[x] \to F[x] \oplus F[x]$?

Comment: @Helen: You're looking for an isomorphism. Its inverse will also be an isomorphism, so you can first find the inverse, which I've suggested, prove that it is an isomorphism, and then work out its inverse. Or you could work out the inverse of my suggestion and prove that it's the desired isomorphism.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! Thanks

Comment: @Helen: You're welcome.